# How to 'clear' the port when restarting django runserver

Tags: django

Often, when restarting Django runserver, if I use the same port number, I get a 'port is already in use' message.  Subsequently, I need to increment the port number each time to avoid this.

It's not the case on all servers, however, so I'm wondering how I might achieve this on the current system that I'm working on?

BTW, the platform is Ubuntu 8.10

Comment: This problem applies to more than just Django, So perhaps we can change the title? I ran into this error when running an Angular app. I found this question with google search `how to kill port 8000` yet this applied to me as well. By changing the title and making the scope more general, we could prevent some redundant questions later.

Comment: try this `sudo fuser -k 8001/tcp`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're getting that message because the server is already running (possibly in the background). Make sure to kill the process (bring it to the foreground and press ctrl-c) to stop the process.

Comment: Ctrl+z is undo.  If you don't see a command prompt, your server is still running.

Comment: ctrl-z puts a process in the background, so one could see a command prompt, even though the server is still running (in the background).

Comment: fg brings it to the foreground. Then press ctrl+c to stop/close it.

Answer (score 128):

I found this information (originally from Kristinn Örn Sigurðsson) to solve my problem:

To kill it with -9 you will have to list all running manage.py processes, for instance:

```
ps aux | grep -i manage
```

You'll get an output similar to this if you've started on many ports:

```
14770     8264  0.0  1.9 546948 40904 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8006
14770    15215  0.0  2.7 536708 56420 ?        S    Sep13   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
14770    30144  0.0  2.1 612488 44912 ?        S    Sep18   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
14770    30282  0.0  1.9 678024 40104 ?        S    Sep18   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002
14770    30592  0.0  2.1 678024 45008 ?        S    Sep18   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8003
14770    30743  0.0  2.1 678024 45044 ?        S    Sep18   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8004
```

Then you'll have to select the pid (which is the second number on the left) for the right manage.py process (python manage.py runserver... etc) and do:

```
kill -9 pid
```

For the above example, if you wanted to free up port 8000, you'd do:

```
kill -9 30144
```

Comment: Just want to add that this solution worked for a colleague running Python 2.6.2 on OS X Lion, Django 1.2.0b1. Thanks!

Comment: I stopped the Django server with Ctrl+C but the process kept running. This answer was the solution, it should be accepted.

Comment: "ps aux | grep -i runserver" seemed to give less output than "ps aux | grep -i manage".

Answer (score 30):

If the `ps aux` command (as per Meilo's answer) doesn't list the process that you wanted to kill but shows the port active in `netstat -np | grep 8004` network activity, try this command (worked on Ubuntu).

```
sudo fuser -k 8004/tcp
```

where as, 8004 is the port number that you want to close. 
This should kill all the processes associated with port 8004.

Comment: On mac use: `sudo lsof -t -i tcp:8000 | xargs kill -9` Hat tip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239232/error-that-port-is-already-in-use

Answer (score 14):

No, he's not an idiot guys. Same thing happens to me. Apparently it's a bug with the python UUID process with continues running long after the django server is shutdown which ties the port up.

Comment: I have the same issue in leopard.

I close it with Ctrl-C and still the port is blocked.

Answer (score 11):

```
fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

Run in terminal it works in ubutu. `8000` is the port.

Comment: I'm getting this error, and have tried this.  Do you have any other solutions?

Comment: It turns out that postgres was not running.  If Postgres is not running, it doesn't listen on port 5432.  I started it and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

## This error is due to the server already running.

### Background

I am answering on a more general level not specific to Django like the original question asks. So that those that land here from Google can easily fix the problem.

### Solution

When you need to clear a port, all you need to do is these two steps

1. In the terminal run `fg`
2. Press Control-C (if on a mac)

### Explanation

[fg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fg_%28Unix%29) brings the process to the *foreground*. Then Control-C stops the server.

### Example

I was actually having this issue with my port 8000 when running an angular app. I was getting an error when I ran `npm start`

[image: Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 start script error]

So I ran `fg`, then I stopped the server with Control-C
[image: fg]
Then I was able to successfully run the server
[image: npm start]

Answer (score 7):

Type `fg` in the terminal to bring up the background task to the foreground.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to close/stop the running server.

Answer (score 6):

I use `pkill -If 'manage.py'` (`-I` means interactive, `-f` matches more than just the process name). See [How to kill all processes with a given partial name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987037/how-to-kill-all-processes-with-a-given-partial-name) for more info on pkill.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:8000 | xargs kill -9
```

If you want to free 8000 port than just copy command and paste in your cmd it will ask for sudo password. And then you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

If the port number that you are trying is 8001, then use this command

```
sudo fuser -k 8001/tcp
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to simply increment the port number when restarting a Django server. This will result in having multiple instances of the Django server running simultaneously. A better solution is to kill the current instance and start a new instance.

To do this, you have multiple options. The easiest is

**Python2:** `$ killall -9 python`

**Python3:** `$ killall -9 python3`

If for some reason, this doesn't work, you can do

`$ kill <pid>` where `<pid>` is the process id found from a simple `$ ps aux | grep python` command.

Answer (score 1):

```
netstat -tulpn |grep 8000|awk '{print $7}'|cut -d/ -f 1|xargs kill
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer: I was about to go write this response, because netstat gets to the heart of the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Repost from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27138521/1467342:

You can use this script in place of `./manage.py runserver`. I put it in `scripts/runserver.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=$(ps aux | grep "./manage.py runserver" | grep -v grep | head -1 | xargs | cut -f2 -d" ")

if [[ -n "$pid" ]]; then
    kill $pid
fi

fuser -k 8000/tcp
./manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mipadi said, you should be terminating the server (ctrl+c) and returning to the command prompt before calling `manage.py runserver` again.

The only thing that could be disrupting this would be if you've somehow managed to make runserver act as a daemon.  If this is the case, I'm guessing you're using the Django test server as the actual web server, which you should *NOT* do.  The Django test server is single threaded, slow and fragile, suitable only for local development.

Comment: no, I've had this problem too... specifially when allowing eclipse to manage terminating the test server... I think it might happen as a result of something in the test server freezing up

Comment: I'd recommend simply starting the test server and letting it run.  It automatically detects changes to your python files and restarts itself.  No need to hit a 'run' button.

Answer (score 0):

In Leopard, I bring on the Activity Monitor and kill python. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Happened so often that I wrote an alias to kill the process with `python` in the name (careful if you have other such processes). Now I just run (no Ubuntu)

```
kill $(ps | grep "python" | awk "{print $1}")
```

You can even add `python manage.py runserver ...` to the same alias so you can restart with two keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

You must have been doing control + z .. Instead do control + c that will kill the server session... Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following library in **manage.py**

> import os
>    import subprocess
>    import re

Now add the following python code after **if __name__ == "__main__":**

```
ports = ['8000']
popen = subprocess.Popen(['netstat', '-lpn'],
                         shell=False,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(data, err) = popen.communicate()
pattern = "^tcp.*((?:{0})).* (?P<pid>[0-9]*)/.*$"
pattern = pattern.format(')|(?:'.join(ports))
prog = re.compile(pattern)
for line in data.split('\n'):
    match = re.match(prog, line)
    if match:
        pid = match.group('pid')
        subprocess.Popen(['kill', '-9', pid])
```

**This will first find the process id of port 8000 , will kill it and then restart  your project. Now each time you don't need to kill the pid manually.**

Answer (score -1):

```
netstat -ntlp
```

See my complete answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34824239/5215825

Comment: `netstat -ntlp` just shows the active connections, ports, and PIDs. In fact, a better way to get the PID would be `ps aux` or more specifically `ps aux | grep python` to see the python and python3 instances.