# How to kill all processes with a given partial name?

Tags: linux, bash, posix

I want to kill all processes that I get by:

```
ps aux | grep my_pattern
```

How to do it?

This does not work:

```
pkill my_pattern
```

Comment: Is `my_pattern` simply a substring of the name, or does it contain any regex special characters?

Comment: I wasn't the one who closed it, but that is most likely the case. https://unix.stackexchange.com/ is the site for Unix and Linux related questions :) @ryanjdillon

Answer (score 1771, accepted):

Use `pkill -f`, which matches the pattern for any part of the command line

```
pkill -f my_pattern
```

Just in case it doesn't work, try to use this one as well:

```
pkill -9 -f my_pattern
```

Comment: @Jayan: it's also quite indiscriminate in its killing. It's surprisingly easy to mishandle...

Comment: @Jayan: you are not going to convince me :-). I have been burnt way too many times by third-party scripts that insisted on using `pkill` - the most common mistake being the assumption that only one instance of each binary could exist at any given time.

Comment: For any Mac users who find this answer, like I did, the Mac equivalent is `killall -m my_pattern`.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg I found that `killall -m` does not match anything, but instead pkill does. They are both dangerous nuke though.

Comment: Will "pkill -f my_pattern", kill multiple services to, or just one (first?) service that will match the pattern?

Comment: @StasS - "pkill -f my_pattern" will terminate all matching processes.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I have to use the pipe (ps, grep and kill) to kill the specific PIDs of all the processes contain a pattern.

Comment: If you have a number of hanging processes which do not get killed use pkill -f -9 to mercilessly kill them

Comment: I recommend using `pgrep` first to verify what you are going to kill. You can use `pgrep -l` to see process names or `pgrep -a` to see full command lines. It uses the same flags as pkill. So in this case you could use `pgrep -fa my_pattern`.

Comment: Flag `-f` means: search complete process name

Comment: I'd recommend adding the `-I` flag (capital `i`) so that it asks for confirmation before killing each matched process. Harder to shoot yourself in the foot that way.

Comment: Didn't work for me, only killed one out of four. The "One liner:" solution below worked.

Comment: if without `-f`, which part will it match?

Comment: What means "pattern". Regex? Please add examples.

Comment: For the timorous there's also the `-x` option for pkill: "match exactly with the command name".  Also on my machine there is no `-I` option.

Comment: To get this to kill processes that I start on boot (from a script in `/etc/init.d`), I needed to use `sudo pkill --signal SIGTERM -f process_name`

Comment: pkill -9 is better.

Comment: @SmallChess is correct. I had 10 jobs that would only die using `pkill -9 -f my_pattern`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix man, you are the only right here =)

Comment: I am getting "pkill: killing pid 47936 failed: Operation not permitted". It's ridiculous that kill is allowed but pkill needs ``sudo``.

Answer (score 272):

### Kill all processes matching the string "myProcessName":

```
ps -ef | grep 'myProcessName' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9
```

Source: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1138/ps-ef-grep-process-grep-v-grep-awk-print-2-xargs-kill-9

**Why "ps pipe kill" from terminal is evil:**

The Piping of integers you scraped from `ps -ef` to `kill -9` is bad, and you should feel bad, doubly so if you're root or a user with elevated privileges, because it doesn't give your process a chance to cleanly shut down socket connections, clean up temp files, inform its children that it is going away or reset its terminal characteristics.

Instead send 15, and wait a second or two, and if that doesn't
work, send 2, and if that doesn't work, send 1.  If that doesn't,
REMOVE THE BINARY because the program is badly behaved.

As a general principle we don't use Unix Railgun to trim the hedges.  https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#kill

**Explanation of above command:**

`ps -ef` produces a list of process id's on the computer visible to this user.  The pipe grep filters that down for rows containing that string.  The `grep -v grep` says don't match on the process itself doing the grepping.  The pipe awk print says split the rows on default delimiter whitespace and filter to the second column which is our process id.  The pipe xargs spins up a new process to send all those pid's to `kill -9`, ending them all.

### Why `ps pipe kill` is bad, dangerous, ugly and hackish:

1. There's a small possibility that you will accidentally end the operating system or cause undefined behavior in an unrelated process, leading to whole system instability because `ps -ef` lists thousands of processes, and you can't be sure some 3rd party process shares your process name, or that in the time between read and execute kill -9, the processid had changed to something else, and now you've ended some random necessary process unrelated to yours.
2. If the code being force-ended is doing any database ops or secure transactions with low probability race conditions, some fraction of a percent of the time, atomicity of that transaction will be wrecked, producing undefined behavior.  kill -9 takes no prisoners.  If your code is sensitive to this, try replacing the `xargs kill` part with a transmitted flag that requests a graceful shutdown, and only if that request is denied, last-resort to `kill -9`

**But,** if you understand all the risks and control for them with unique names, and you're ok with a few dropped transactions or occasional corruption, then 99.9% of the time yer gonna be fine. If there's a problem, reboot the computer, make sure there aren't any process collisions.  It's because of code like this that makes the tech support script: "Have you tried restarting your computer" a level 5 meme.  "A Rogue Robot scraped `ps` to find integers and sent those to `kill -9`, so reboot the computer to clear the problem.

### Why not just use `pkill` which is easier?

The above gives me manual control because `ps`, `grep`, `awk`, `kill` and `xargs` are multi-platform standard.  It gives full control to which regex engine to use, which part of the process name to match, handling case sensitivity and exception management.

```
pkill -f -e -c myProcessName
```

Does the same thing for me, but see `man pkill` has different behaviors, flags and regex engines between variants of Linux, Mac, Zune-Bash and my opensource router.  So yes, put your 35000 Watt Unix-Railgun into the capable hands of pkill to trim the hedges.  See what happens.

### Grepping once

You can substitute the `grep -v grep |` with square brackets around the first letter of the command to kill, which does the same thing and prevents grep from grepping itself, for example:

```
ps -ef | grep '[m]yProcessName' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9
```

Why that works:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/153419/how-does-this-tricky-bracket-expression-in-grep-work

Comment: Just a slight modification, perhaps it is better to quote the process name:


`ps -ef | grep 'myProcessName' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9`

Without quotes, only one of my background processes was killed on the first run. Running it again killed the rest.

Comment: `-r` option doesn't exist on OS X, so it seems.

Comment: @Eric-Leschinski `pkill -e` option is not available in CentOS7 that is to say with `pkill (procps version 3.2.8)`

Answer (score 57):

If you need more flexibility in selecting the processes use

```
for KILLPID in `ps ax | grep 'my_pattern' | awk ' { print $1;}'`; do 
  kill -9 $KILLPID;
done
```

You can use grep -e etc.

Comment: -1 You don't need a loop, you can just `kill -9 \`ps ax | awk '[m]y_pattern { print $1 }'\`` (note also the refactoring; see also my comment on @synthesizerpatel's answer).

Comment: @tripleee No problem with your downvote, but you **do** realize, that the OQ was *"I want to kill all processes that I get by: ps aux | grep my_pattern"*, which I dutyfully accepted.

Comment: Kill will kill all the processes in one go, you don't need a loop for that.  If the `ps` returns three processes 123, 234, and 345, you can `kill 123 234 345` just like you can `rm` or `cat` multiple file arguments.

Comment: @tripleee I ment removing the `grep`

Comment: `for KILLPID in `ps ax | grep 'puma' | grep -v 'grep' | awk ' { print $1;}'`; do kill -9 $KILLPID; done` will remove the grep

Answer (score 21):

you can use the following command to list the process

```
ps aux | grep -c myProcessName
```

if you need to check the count of that process then run

```
ps aux | grep -c myProcessName |grep -v grep
```

after which you can kill the process using

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep -e myProcessName | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

Comment: you can use the following command to list the process

ps aux | grep -c myProcessName 

if you need to check the count of that process then run 

ps aux | grep -c myProcessName |grep -v grep

after which you can kill the process using 

kill -9 $(ps aux | grep -e myProcessName | awk '{ print $2 }')

Answer (score 18):

Also you can use `killall -r my_pattern`. *`-r` Interpret process name pattern as an extended regular expression.*

```
killall -r my_pattern
```

Answer (score 8):

If you judge `pkill -f PATTERN` a bit too dangerous, I wrote [ezkill](https://github.com/Kraymer/ezkill) a bash script that prompt you to choose which processes amongst those that match the PATTERN you want to kill.

Warning: This project is no more maintained.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following command to

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 'process' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 7):

If you do not want to take headache of finding process id, use regexp to kill process by name. For example, to kill chrome following code will do the trick.

`killall -r chrome`

Comment: You only need either `-r` _or_ `--regexp`, which are the short and the GNU long option, respectively.

Answer (score 6):

Found the best way to do it  for a server which does not support `pkill`

```
kill -9 $(ps ax | grep My_pattern| fgrep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

You do not have to loop.

Answer (score 5):

This is the way:

```
kill -9 $(pgrep -d' ' -f chrome)
```

The pgrep searches for all processes related to `chrome` and returns them in a list separated by spaces.

This is passed to the `kill` application that can safely `kill` all the related `chrome` processes.

This is still dangerous, be careful.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: first the pgrep search for all processes related to chrome and return them in a list separated by space. This is pass to the kill application that can safety kill all the related chrome processes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command to:

```
ps -ef | grep -i myprocess | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9
```

or

```
ps -aux | grep -i myprocess | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9
```

It works for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use 4-space or tab indentation for your code lines so that they are formatted as code blocks. Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Sounds bad?

```
 pkill `pidof myprocess`
```

example:

```
# kill all java processes
pkill `pidof java`
```

Answer (score 1):

it's best and safest to use `pgrep -f` with `kill`, or just `pkill -f`, `grep`ing `ps`'s output can go wrong.

Unlike using `ps | grep` with which you need to filter out the grep line by adding `| grep -v` or using pattern tricks, `pgrep` just won't pick itself by design.

Moreover, should your pattern appear in `ps`'s `UID`/`USER`, `SDATE`/`START` or any other column, you'll get unwanted processes in the output and kill them, `pgrep`+`pkill` don't suffer from this flaw.

also I found that `killall -r`***/*** `-regexp` didn't work with my regular expression.

`pkill -f "^python3 path/to/my_script$"`

[`man pkill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)

Answer (score 0):

I took Eugen Rieck's answer and worked with it. My code adds the following:

1. `ps ax` includes grep, so I excluded it with `grep -Eiv 'grep'`
2. Added a few ifs and echoes to make it human-readable.

I've created a file, named it `killserver`, here it goes:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
PROCESS_TO_KILL=bin/node
PROCESS_LIST=`ps ax | grep -Ei ${PROCESS_TO_KILL} | grep -Eiv 'grep' | awk ' { print $1;}'`
KILLED=
for KILLPID in $PROCESS_LIST; do
  if [ ! -z $KILLPID ];then
    kill -9 $KILLPID
    echo "Killed PID ${KILLPID}"
    KILLED=yes
  fi
done

if [ -z $KILLED ];then
    echo "Didn't kill anything"
fi
```

Results

```sh
➜  myapp git:(master) bash killserver
Killed PID 3358
Killed PID 3382
Killed
➜  myapp git:(master) bash killserver
Didn't kill anything
```