# Using a shell script to automatically kill processes

Tags: linux, shell

I am looking for a command that will find PIDs such as:

```
ps -ef | grep com.sds.afi.rte.cosmos-1.0.0.jar
cosmos    4690  4689  3 14:27 pts/8    00:00:06 java -Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/data/cosmos/sim/bin/log4j.xml -jar com.sds.afi.rte.cosmos-1.0.0.jar
cosmos    5484  5482  0 14:30 pts/11   00:00:00 grep com.sds.afi.rte.cosmos-1.0.0.jar
```

and then kill these processes using:

```
kill -9 pid
```

How can I make a shell script that will do all the above automatically ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to kill all processes with a given partial name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987037/how-to-kill-all-processes-with-a-given-partial-name)

Answer (score 13):

`killall java`

Or more generically:

`killall <processname>`

Sometimes I have processes with the same name, but different command line arguments. To kill such processes or any arbitrary process without having to type in ps and then kill pid, I do this:

`ps aux | grep <something> | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill`

where

- `<something>` is any phrase that you want to search for in the ps aux
  command's output.
- `awk '{print $2}'` will filter out only the 2nd
  column, which is a list of PIDs
- `kill` will be called on each of
  those PIDs.

Edit: As tripleee points out, it is a bad idea to lash out `kill -9` on a process unless absolutely needed. So removed the `-9` part from the above command

Comment: The `grep 'a' | awk '{b}'` antipattern can be simplified into `awk 'a{b}'`.  See also http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html which additionally advises against `kill -9` unless you really, really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

I think `pkill -9 java` is the easiest way. `pkill` will use grep to find a matching process name.

See the manual page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
kill -9 `pidof java`
```

Comment: [cosmos@afisvr2:/data/cosmos/sim/bin] kill -9 'pidof com.sds.afi.rte.cosmos-1.0.0.jar'
-bash: kill: pidof com.sds.afi.rte.cosmos-1.0.0.jar: arguments must be process or job IDs

Comment: It worked for me, but I had to put the whole command text (exactly the same that you get in `ps` output). Using the question's example, it should be: ``kill -9 `pidof "java -Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/data/cosmos/sim/bin/log4j.xml -jar com.sds.afi.rte.cosmos-1.0.0.jar"` ``

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution [ErJab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123545/erjab) provided, I created a shell script killall to mimic the 'killall' behaviour:

```
#!/bin/sh
ps | grep $1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9
```

Which I placed in the /bin directory (after chmod +x, of course)

[qnx](/questions/tagged/qnx)

Answer (score 0):

I find the **`pkill`/`pgrep`** commands as mentioned by `nikeairj` the best choice if available.
I also used the following which may also work in Linux/Unix OSes **without `awk` or other possibly unavailable commands** (I remember not beeing able to use `awk` in some **`AIX`** or **`HP-UX`** environments)

```
# subsitute myMatch with your process cmdline match, e.g. "firefox", "firefox -P"
# or anything output by "ps -ef"
ps -ef|grep myMatch|grep -v grep|sed -e "s/^[^0-9]\+\([0-9]\+\)\s.\+$/\1/"|xargs kill "{}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include below command in your shell script which will kill the process id for "com.sds.afi.rte.cosmos-1.0.0.jar"

kill -9 `ps aux | grep com.sds.afi.rte.cosmos-1.0.0.jar | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}'`

make sure you use inverted (``) comma for pid search as used above.

if you want to execute the above command from expect command then you can use below:

expect "$"

send "kill -9 `ps aux | grep com.sds.afi.rte.cosmos-1.0.0.jar | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}'`\r"

Cheers,
Suraj

Answer (score 0):

I made a .sh to restart my Wifi after putting it in monitor mode with the following lines.

```
#Display PID

echo "Killing network PID'S"

ps aux | grep wpa_supplicant | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill



ps aux | grep NetworkManager | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill

#Restart NetworkManager && wpa_supplicant

echo "Restarting NetworkManager && wpa_supplicant"

service NetworkManager restart && service wpa_supplicant restart
```