# How to stop the execution of a php script in another page?

Tags: php, sockets, ratchet

I've just learned how to setup and start a web-socket server using Ratchet.

I've learned how to start the script using a command from the terminal and the script keeps running forever.

What I want to know now, is how can I start and stop that script (the web-socket server) using php code, not terminal, So that I can have a button to start and stop the web-socket server whenever I want ?

This question might seem naive, but I don't have a clue on how to this, I am new to Ratchet and web-socket.

Comment: We are using a service to start and stop the Websocket on Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the pid, then just use command,

```
exec("kill -9 $pid");
```

Otherwise, you can use

```
exec("pkill $progname"); //To kill a any command with name as $progname
```

Please refer to this for more such options.

[How to kill all processes with a given partial name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987037/how-to-kill-all-processes-with-a-given-partial-name)

Comment: what do you mean by **with name as $progname**, can you give an example?

Comment: $progname defines the name of the program which you want to kill. For example if you want to kill terminals,  use "pkill  -f term"

This will kill any program which has a pattern like term. If avoid -f then you have to give exact program name like say your script , "shellscript.sh" 

$progname will store the name "shellscript.sh"