# Kill tomcat service running on any port, Mac Sierra

Tags: macos, tomcat, tcp, process

Kill tomcat service running on any port, Mac using terminal like 8080/ 8005

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239232/django-server-error-port-is-already-in-use) , answer already given on this link.

Comment: You are right , it's just more about specific keyword mentioned in the question so people can easily relate .

Answer (score 7):

1. Go to Launchpad Type Terminal
2. Run the following commands:

For all listening ports

```
netstat -vanp tcp
```

Apply port filter

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 8080
```

Finally, with the PID we can run the following command to kill the process

Copy PID from the result set

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Example:  `kill -9 1234`

Done !!

Find similar answer :
[Django Server Error: port is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239232/django-server-error-port-is-already-in-use)

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal:

lsof -n -iTCP:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN -n -l -P | grep 'LISTEN' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

lsof -n -iTCP:8005 -sTCP:LISTEN -n -l -P | grep 'LISTEN' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9