# How to stop the node.js inspector / Chrome Debugger on SIGINT?

Tags: node.js, express, node-inspector

I have the following code to capture a ^C from the terminal and gracefully shutdown my Express app:

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    console.log('SIGINT received ...');
    console.log('Shutting down the server');

    server.close(() => {
        console.log('Server has been shutdown');
        console.log('Exiting process ...');
        process.exit(0);
    });
});
```

However if I start my node instance with `--inspect`, then the above code fails to stop the inspector and the Chrome debugger. When I restart my application, I get the following error:

```
Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use
```

How do I gracefully stop my app to avoid this error?

Full code available [here](https://github.com/archfirst/graphql-bookstore-server/blob/master/src/index.js).

Comment: Hey, did you found a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, still an issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: That port is already in use.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239232/error-that-port-is-already-in-use)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It seems that VSCode, Puppeteer, nodemon, express, etc. causes this problem,
you ran a process in the background or just closed the debugging area [browser, terminal, etc. ] or whatever , 
anyway, you can in CMD run

```
$ ps ax | grep node
```

then

```
$ killall -9 node
```

it is not the best solution, also, i may suggest that you look for the process using this port then send close signal

```
$ sudo ss -lptn 'sport = :9229'
```

OR

```
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep :9229
```

OR

```
$ sudo lsof -n -i :9229 | grep LISTEN
```

THEN:

```
$ sudo kill <pid>
```

OR JUST [the two steps in one]

```
$ sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:9229`
```

OR

```
$ sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:9229)
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
fuser -k -n tcp 9229
```

Answer (score 4):

To kill all node process

> taskkill /im node.exe

```
or forcefully
```

> taskkill /f /im node.exe

Answer (score 3):

I had the same terminal error from nodemon, even though I thought I'd quit all terminal processes, but simply quitting VSCode and reopening solved for me (thanks to [KhogaEslam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49797588/2501304) for the hint).

Hope this helps someone else too!

Answer (score 0):

was at a node docker. with `ss`, complete, if u know the port is open:

```
kill `ss -lptn 'sport = :THE_PORT' | tail -n1 | cut -d, -f2 | cut -d= -f2`
```

Comment: testing for it:
    timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/localhost/THE_PORT'

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that if you are starting a script with say `yarn dev` then yarn will run a separate debug node process that will take the first port, then if the debugger is lenient it will try the next port and boom you have 2 ports 9229 and then next 9230.

So the solution is to actually invoke the script directly so that node debugs the actual script and assign the port you are expecting.

eg: if my package.json has `"dev": "app develop"` in its script section and I normally run that with `yarn dev` on the commandline. Doing `NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect yarn dev` will cause this issue. The solution will be to run `NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect app develop`, this invokes what yarn was going to do in the script.