# NodeJS debug Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:42457 failed: address already in use error

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

I am trying to debug my Discord bot using the DiscordJS lib. My trouble is that when I start a debug session (launching with vscode or with --inspect-brk | --debug-brk)

I get a `Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:42457 failed: address already in use` error I have tried changing the port in both situations and still getting the same error on different ports. My bot is sharded so its start child process of itself. I have tried using vscode to attach to child processes but still the same error.

If anybody is familiar with DiscordJS and knows how to debug a sharded bot some help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you starting the server bound to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49797588/222356 has a great answer on how to kill a process using a specific port. Killing all your node processes (per an answer below) is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case to solve this, just add that config on nodemon.json

```
{
 "execMap": {
  "js": "node --inspect=9300 -r sucrase/register"
  }
}
```

I added --inspect=9300 to set port to this specific port

Answer (score -1):

First Ctrl C (or Cmd C) to quit all your progress in the cmd.

```
Start Task Manager > Find all tasks named "node" > End process.
```

Now go back to your cmd and start server.

Answer (score -2):

That is because you are already running that application in with `node filename.js`, hence stop that process and start with debugging again with same port.

You can take a look that on the below video might help

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8e9RAekktY&t=28s

Comment: My current launcher for vscode is this `{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Shards.js"
        }` I dont see what you said can fix it?

Comment: Can you try `killall node` this will kill all the running node sever and start directly debugging

Comment: Are you using Chrome debugger or VS Code Debugger

Comment: VS Code Debugger

Comment: Okay not sure even I was facing the same issue but killing node and directly running debug solved my problem!!

Comment: Issue related to this is here https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/1714