# I am getting these error a lot in django running on my ubuntu pc

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

Though i stop the all server still i am getting these error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0hff.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Server Error: port is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239232/django-server-error-port-is-already-in-use)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run this command: `python manage.py migrate`.

If the port is already used then first kill process of that port and try again `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 1):

To solve `Error: That port is already in use`, make sure that you have no other applications running that are using `127.0.0.1:8000`.  If you need help doing that, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239232/django-server-error-port-is-already-in-use).

If that doesn't solve the issue, you can try killing all python process by running `killall python`.

If that still doesn't work, you can run the server on a different port: `python manage.py runserver 7069`

(you also need to run `python manage.py migrate` to apply your migrations)

Comment: Yes but still when i stop the server and start again it's showing same error

Comment: @satyamsingh Did you try killing all Python processes with `killall python`?  Did you try running the server on a different port with `python manage.py runserver 7069`?  Did you check the question I linked to try to kill any possible process on `127.0.0.1:8000`?