# django runserver, port taken

Tags: python, django

```
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:80/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That port is already in use.
```

This is on Ubuntu 14

Actually I tried netstat -ap |grep 80 
but no process is using 80...

btw, I used 80 for django before. After an unexpected sudden shut down, restart, it show the error above.

The answer of [How to 'clear' the port when restarting django runserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880239/how-to-clear-the-port-when-restarting-django-runserver) does not work for me because I cannot find a process taking 80

---

P.S.  if I change 80 to 81 it will work. So it is definitely 80 taken. But I cannot find who take it.

And I've tried sudo

Comment: If you "telnet localhost 80", you should be able to connect to whatever process is on port 80. What happens?

Answer (score 0):

Self answer:

Solved!

In fact, it is similar to another answer. But you should do it separately:

This is **not** working:

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:80 | xargs kill -9
```

This is working:

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:80
kill -9 xxxxxxx
```

replace xx with the pids one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use this command in `linux-ubuntu`

```
fuser -k 80/tcp
```