# Django check if server is already running

Tags: python, django, windows, server

I am on Windows, and run my Django server via `manage.py runserver 8001`. When I have already running server and enter the mentioned command again, it starts another server listening the same (8001) port. What I would like to do is to determine if server is already running and stop the execution of the command, or stop the running server and then run the new server.

**UPDATE:**
I need to do the described things automatically. Throwing an error is also OK.
But why `runserver` command is not throwing an error, if the port is already busy?? That's a standard behavior of platforms that I have experience with (Java Tomcat server, PHP) and also on Ubuntu with Django, as  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880239/how-to-clear-the-port-when-restarting-django-runserver) clarifies.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in using `cmd`:

```
 netstat -ano | findStr "8001"
```

Comment: What about automatic detection? I'd like the runserver command to throw an error if there is a running server on that port (as usually happens in other server solutions).

Comment: `netstat -ano | grep 8000`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are running two Django projects at the same time
either you are running one project using command prompt
and a second project using the IDE terminal

**Solution**

Terminate these two projects running using CTR + C
or check the project that's using the port 8001 by doing this

on your command prompt

```
netstat -ano | findStr "8001"
```

You can also check which process on you machine is being run on which port by doing the following on terminal:

```
netstat -a -b -o -n
```

**-a **Displays all connections and listening ports.

**-b** Displays the executable involved in creating each connection or listening port.

**-n** Displays addresses and port numbers .

**-o** Displays the owning process ID.

Comment: I am just running the same `runserver` command twice using cmd. What I want is to detect this automatically. I'd like the command to throw an error if there is a running server on that port (as usually happens in other server solutions)

Comment: I have worked with django for a while and there's nothing  like that